# FLEX 4.0 Vgroup seems not to draw their elements

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I got a component made with an spark Group for a survey, inside of it I have an algorithm that create the questions putting RadioButtons inside of a VGroup(dynamically).
The problem is that sometimes when I call the next question, I couldn't find why, they are not drawn unless I click the right mouse button so it appears normally.

```
public function nextQuestion(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    destroyQuestion();
    selectNextQuestion();
    creatQuestion();

}


private function destroyQuestion(): void
{
    vgSurvey.removeAllElements();
}



private function createQuestion(): void
{   

    for each(var answer: Answer in currentItem.arrayAnswers)
    {
        var radioAnswer: RadioButton = new RadioButton();               

        radioAnswer.id = answer.id;             

        radioAnswer.label = answer.label;                           

        vgSurvey.addElement(radioAnswer);               

    }   

}


<MXML>

...

     <s:VGroup id="vgSurvey" >                                          

     </s:VGroup>
```

So, when I run the application and I move through the questions, sometimes, the question is not drawn (exemple: I'm at question 2 and I move to the third question and it's blank, but if i press the right button in my mouse the question suddenly appears. So I move to the fourth and everything seems right)

I apologize about my English and hope you guys can help me.

Comment: I don't fully understand.  Please show some code, and perhaps some screenshots demonstrating what is happening and what you wish were happening.

Comment: This is not an answer but I suggest you look into the Form Spark component http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e973827a8e912ac2b325a4-8000.html. It could prove useful to you.

Comment: thanks Exort, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Looks like Flash Player problem, try installing older FP version.
- Try changing container to Tile temporatily - you'll know whether the problem is in VGroup.
- Try using different SDK version - you'll know if it's the problem of your 4.0 SDK (there are some bugs fixed for groups/layouts since 4.0).
- Check if there are runtime exceptions firing during `nextQuestion()` execution by commenting out all your `try/catch` statements.

Comment: Maxim, thanks for your answer. I changed the SDK version and it solved the problem